# Magento 2 Default logo on Email

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, email-templates

I have create observer which sends the email. The email is working file but the problem is with the logo. I have added the logo for the all email. All the emails including the sales order shows me the new logo which i updated. Only this one doesn't.

Here is my observer code

```
    $enableEmail = $this->config->getGeneralConfig('email');
    $ccEmail = explode(",",$this->config->getGeneralConfig('cc_email'));

    $templateOptions = array(
        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
    ); 

     $fileName = "Order #".$orderId.".pdf";
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
                ->setTemplateOptions
                (
                    $templateOptions
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($content)
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($email)
                ->addAttachment($generated_file->render(), $fileName)
                ->addCc($ccEmail)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
```

Here is the template header which is responsible to show logo.

```
      {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
```

The above code is there in sales order. But sales order show the correct logo.

Comment: `->addAttachment` is no vanilla magento functionality, maybe the extension you're using is wrong

Comment: have you define `’email_templates.xml` ?

Comment: @AmitBera Yes..

Comment: @PhilippSander i have commented the statement and checked. Still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to content -> Design -> Configuration
There is no of record on the basis of theme that are using. go to edit action for all records. 
Then slelect the transactional email tabs. there u found logo images. Update this images that u want to display in email headers